# Show image in Fulscreenmode with Intent

Tags: android, image, listview, switch-statement

Hi I need to find a way to start an Intent from clicking a listview item and show me an image with unique ID in fullscreen mode so I can scroll left or right and switch with different images.Any idea how I have to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an onItemClickListener to your ListView, take it's position and add it to your intent.

`Intent i = new Intent(this, newactivity.class);
i.putExtras("key", id);
i.startActivity();`

in the new activity, you can open an xml with 1 imageview that takes up the entire screen.

tho, you ask to scroll left and right, I don't get that part...

so if you have 5 items in listview, and I tap on item 3, I'd get a fullscreen view on image 3, but I'd be able to swipe left and right for previous and next image?

in the new activity you can retrieve your clicked id by doing:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int id = (int) extras.get("key");
```

Comment: yes,exactly! I need to swap between images when I'm on image 3.One question : what is id (is it R.id.imageId) and what is "key"?

Comment: Basicly, you push a bundle into the intent with a key, so in your next activity you can instantiate a new bundle and getExtras from it by key. Anyways, you can create an Integer array with drawables and pass that to the next activity, together with the ID clicked, and in that new activity, make an imageswitcher or gallery filling up the screen, starting at the position of the ID clicked

Comment: the id is the position clicked, forgot to add that

Comment: When I try to do this i.addExtras("key", id); it's saying this :  "The method addExtras(String, long) is undefined for the type Intent".